# Problemas com interpretador R

Tags: r, intellij

Eu fiz a instalação do R4Intellji e selecionei um programa em R. Porém quando eu peço para rodar (run) o programa dá o seguinte erro:

```
The R interpreter is not specified
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Acho difícil encontrar alguém por aqui que possa te ajudar com isto. Eu tenho alguma experiência com a linguagem R e nunca ouvi falar desta IDE. Ela deve ser conhecida por quem programa em outras linguagens que não o R. Existe algum motivo especial para usar esta IDE em vez do RStudio, por exemplo?

Comment: Não há um motivo especifico não. Apenas achei essa IDE mais interessante que do RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não conheço esta IDE específica, porém se ela funcionar como outras IDEs da Intellij você tem que ir em File -> Project Interpreter e lá você escolhe o R como interpretador do código que você escrever na IDE.